# multi linear regression model. Modeling with a heavily skewed binary independent variable

Tags: r, multiple-regression, predictive-models, large-data, rare-events

Dataset and goal:
One continuous measurement( to be modeled as a dependent variable) and four other measurements (one binary  and the rest are category variables with multiple levels) to be modeled as independent variables.

dataset samples: roughly 3 million rows

model used: multilinear regression.

The binary independent variable is very heavily skewed.i.e. 3% samples are true and the rest are false.

Does it make sense to use such an independent variable in a multi linear regression model?. what should I be careful about while modeling with such a situation?

Comment: The main thing I would be worried about, given your sample size, is that you would find statistical significance even though there is no "practical" (or in my field, clinical) significance of the finding.  I'm curious, though what the distributions look like for your other categorical variables